# Sitecore language prefix not setting language cookie

Tags: multilingual, link-manager

This didn't seem to be an issue until recently. I have a language toggle on my site for English/French that when clicked, adds the appropriate language prefix to the current URL (e.g. /products -> /fr-ca/products). When the url with the language prefix loads it's in the correct language, however when I navigate to another page it's back in the original language. I checked the language cookie and it appears the language cookie is not getting updated, it's still "en" after visiting /fr-ca/...

Comment: Do the links on the page also include the language prefix?

Comment: No, the links on the page have no language prefix. Previously once the language was set once with a language prefix, subsequent URLs didn't need to have a language prefix to continue to display in that language

Comment: Have you tried using Sitecore.Context.SetLanguage() to force sitecore to Switch the language when user changes the language on the site?

Comment: I have not. Previously using the language prefix worked to set the language and I'm trying to figure out why that' snot working anymore